# Can't seem to return a nested array within an object fetched with the fetch API. I can return the whole object, but not the properties inside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying to render some data that I'm fetching from the Open Trivia DB. But when I try to map an array (which is the value of am object property), I get undefined on the console.

For now, I want to console.log the array within the object property when the state changes. Later I want to map the results Array to properly render some of the data within the array of objects.

Here's my code:

```js
export default function App(){
  const [quizScreen, setQuizScreen] = useState(false)

  const questions = (
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=26&difficulty=medium')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>   data)
  )

const startQuiz = () => {
 
  setQuizScreen(prevScreen => !prevScreen)
  console.log(questions.results) //works if I log questions, but not questions.results


}
```

This is the data:

```js
{
    "response_code":0,
    "results":[
       {
          "category":"Celebrities",
          "type":"multiple",
          "difficulty":"medium",
          "question":"Which actress&#039;s real name was Frances Ethel Gumm?",
          "correct_answer":"Judy Garland",
          "incorrect_answers":[
             "Doris Day",
             "Julie Andrews",
             "Marilyn Monroe"
          ]
       },
       {
          "category":"Celebrities",
          "type":"multiple",
          "difficulty":"medium",
          "question":"What is the real name of &quot;moot&quot;, founder of the imageboard 4chan?",
          "correct_answer":"Christopher Poole",
          "incorrect_answers":[
             "Mark Zuckerberg",
             "Allison Harvard",
             "Catie Wayne"
          ]
       },
       {
          "category":"Celebrities",
          "type":"multiple",
          "difficulty":"medium",
          "question":"Before voicing Pearl in Steven Universe, Deedee Magno Hall was part of which American band?",
          "correct_answer":"The Party",
          "incorrect_answers":[
             "The Weather Girls",
             "The Pussycat Dolls",
             "The Cheetah Girls"
          ]
       },
       {
          "category":"Celebrities",
          "type":"multiple",
          "difficulty":"medium",
          "question":"Who out of these actresses is the youngest?",
          "correct_answer":"Kiernan Shipka",
          "incorrect_answers":[
             "Ariel Winter",
             "Emma Watson",
             "Bonnie Wright"
          ]
       },
       {
          "category":"Celebrities",
          "type":"multiple",
          "difficulty":"medium",
          "question":"Who is &quot;James Rolfe&quot; better known as?",
          "correct_answer":"The Angry Video Game Nerd",
          "incorrect_answers":[
             "TotalBiscuit",
             "PeanutButterGamer",
             "PewDiePie"
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous and returns a promise not the actual data.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks a lot, is there a way to actually retrieve the data when the promise is fullfilled??

Comment: `questions.then(data=> console.log(data.results))`